# SQL Server 2012 Management Studio error while trying to open the SQL text editor

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssms, text-editor

I have a weird error while trying to open the SQL text editor in SSMS 2012. The error throws in any options like New Query, Modify a stored procedure, Select top 1000 rows, any action that opens the script editor. When I enter to Tools/Options/TextEditor/[Any language] the program breaks and shows a Windows error.

This is the weird error. I copied the error details but it means nothing to me.

[image: This the weird error]

> ===================================
>
> Internal error occurred. Additional information: ''. (mscorlib)
>
> ------------------------------ Program Location:
>
> at
>   System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ImportEngine.InPrerequisiteLoop()
>   at
>   System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ImportEngine.TrySatisfyImportsStateMachine(PartManager
>   partManager, ComposablePart part)    at
>   System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ImportEngine.TrySatisfyImports(PartManager
>   partManager, ComposablePart part, Boolean shouldTrackImports)    at
>   System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ImportEngine.SatisfyImports(ComposablePart
>   part)    at
>   System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.CompositionServices.GetExportedValueFromComposedPart(ImportEngine
>   engine, ComposablePart part, ExportDefinition definition)    at
>   System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.CatalogExportProvider.GetExportedValue(CatalogPart
>   part, ExportDefinition export, Boolean isSharedPart)    at
>   System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.CatalogExportProvider.CatalogExport.GetExportedValueCore()
>   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Primitives.Export.get_Value()
>   at
>   System.ComponentModel.Composition.ExportServices.GetCastedExportedValue[T](Export
>   export)    at
>   System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ExportProvider.GetExportedValueCore[T](String
>   contractName, ImportCardinality cardinality)    at
>   System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ExportProvider.GetExportedValue[T](String
>   contractName)    at
>   System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ExportProvider.GetExportedValueT
>   at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentModelHost.ComponentModel.GetServiceT
>   at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.VsDocDataAdapter.SetSite(Object
>   pUnkSite)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.VsTextBufferAdapter.SetSite(Object
>   pUnkSite)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.ShellTextBuffer.SetSite(Object
>   serviceProvider)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.ShellTextEditorControl.CreateAndInitTextBuffer(Object
>   sp)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.Editors.ScriptEditorControl.Initialize(Object
>   sp)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.Editors.ScriptAndResultsEditorControl.Initialize(Object
>   sp)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.Editors.SqlScriptEditorControl.Initialize(Object
>   sp, String moniker)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.Editors.SqlScriptEditorControl.CreateInstance(Object
>   serviceProvider, Boolean withEncoding, String moniker)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.Editors.EditorFactorySql.CreateEditorInstance(IServiceProvider
>   serviceProvider, Boolean storeActiveConnIfNeeded, String moniker)
>   at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.Editors.EditorFactoryBase.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsEditorFactory.CreateEditorInstance(UInt32
>   createFlags, String moniker, String physicalView, IVsHierarchy
>   hierarchy, UInt32 itemId, IntPtr existingDocData, IntPtr&
>   docViewIntPtr, IntPtr& docDataIntPtr, String& caption, Guid&
>   cmdUIGuid, Int32& result)    at
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32
>   errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.Editors.ScriptFactory.CreateNewScript(String
>   strFullPathToScript, IVsProject projectToAddScriptTo,
>   UIConnectionGroupInfo connectionInfoList, IDbConnection liveCon,
>   String rootName)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.Editors.ScriptFactory.CreateNewScript(String
>   strFullPathToScript, IVsExternalFilesManager extFileMgr,
>   UIConnectionGroupInfo connectionInfoList, IDbConnection liveCon,
>   String rootName)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.Editors.ScriptFactory.CreateNewScript(String
>   strFullPathToScript, UIConnectionGroupInfo connectionInfoList,
>   IDbConnection liveCon, String fileRoot)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.Editors.ScriptFactory.CreateNewScript(String
>   strFullPathToScript, UIConnectionInfo ci, IDbConnection liveCon)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.ObjectExplorer.NewQueryMenuHandler.Invoke()
>   at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.ObjectExplorer.ToolsMenuItemBase.MenuInvokedHandler(Object
>   sender, EventArgs args)

I tried to repair SSMS but I don't know where I can do this. 
I can't find Microsoft Sql Server Management Studio in "Programs and Features"

[image]

I executed chkdsk and have no bad sectors on my ssd drive

> Windows has scanned the file system and found no problems. No further
>   action is required.
>
> 131449855 KB total disk space.   54907808 KB in 218559 files.
>       137392 KB in 61261 indexes.
>            0 KB in bad sectors.
>       392375 KB in use by the system.
>        65536 KB occupied by the log file.   76012280 KB available on disk.
>
> ```
>   4096 bytes in each allocation unit.   32862463 total allocation units on disk.   19003070 allocation units available on disk.
> ```

Comment: Repair operation is available when you _uninstall_ SSMS via Control Panel, though a full uninstall/reinstall is probably a better idea just to ensure you're not copying files back into potentially bad sectors on your local disk.  [Here's](https://www.techwalla.com/articles/how-to-repair-sql-server-management-studio) an article that will step you through the process.

Comment: @JohnEisbrener I have Windows 10, and SQL Server Management Studio is not an installed program in "Programs and Features".

Comment: I moved my response to the answer below so I could include a screenshot as well.

Answer (score 1):

The *repair* operation is available when you *uninstall* SSMS via Control Panel, though a full uninstall/reinstall is probably a better idea just to ensure you're not copying files back into potentially bad sectors on your local drive.

[Here's](https://www.techwalla.com/articles/how-to-repair-sql-server-management-studio) an article that will step you through the process.

Per your comment double-check you're looking at the right place, as it should be listed under Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio:

[image]

If it's not there, have you already uninstalled it?  I'm not sure how you can run SSMS without it being installed, but that may very well be the root cause of your issue.  In that case, just install another copy of it and be sure to run a [CHKDSK](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491051.aspx) operation against your local drives to make sure you're not running into any disk corruption.

Comment: I updated my answer to show you that Microsoft Sql Server Management Studio is not in "Programs and Features". Actually I have never seen it at there since I use Windows 10 and Sql Server 2012. I tried with chkdsk. Thanks for your advice. I will try reinstall windows and sql server

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use the updated version of SQL Server Management Studio. You can download it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms). As of this writing, the newest version is 16.5.3. Microsoft usually release monthly updates/patch for SSMS. Try to install it. SSMS 16.5.3 is compatible with SQL Server 2012.